# Artificially adding ggplot squares into standard plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some doubts about one thing. How artificially close can I be to ggplot using standard plot ? For instance let's take two graphs below. First created with standard plot, and second one with ggplot.

```
x<-rnorm(100)
ggplot(data.frame(x),aes(x=1:100))+geom_line(aes(y=x))
as.ggplot(~plot(x,type='l'))
```

[image]

[image]

Is there any possibility to add to image (1) squares that are in image (2) ? How can I copy as much as possible look of second graph to first one without using ggplot ?

Thanks in advcance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get very close, question is why would you want to do that? Anyways, try something like this:

```
x <- rnorm(100)

# calculate the axis limits
limitsX <- c(-1, length(x))
limitsY <- range(x) * 1.1

# get pretty ticks
tickMarksX <- pretty(0:length(x))
tickMarksY <- pretty(x)

# plot
plot(NULL, xlim=limitsX, ylim=limitsY, bty = 'n', xaxs = 'i', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', yaxs = 'i')
rect(limitsX[1], limitsY[1], limitsX[2], limitsY[2], col = "#E0E0E0", border = NA)
axis(1, at = tickMarksX, lwd = 0, ticks.lwd = 1)
axis(2, at = tickMarksY, lwd = 0, ticks.lwd = 1)

# major x grid lines
abline(v = tickMarksX, col = "white", lwd=2)
# minor x grid lines
abline(v = tickMarksX-(tickMarksX[2]-tickMarksX[1])/2, col = "white")

# major y grid lines
abline(h = tickMarksY, col = "white")
# minor y grid lines
abline(h = tickMarksY-(tickMarksY[2]-tickMarksY[1])/2, col = "white")


lines(x = 1:length(x), y = x)
```

[image]

Comment: How did you choose those specific numbers ? I mean, is there a possibility to make it more generic ?

Comment: Sure, work more with `max()`, `min()`, `range()` and increase the axes limits by relative size like `max(x) * 1.25`

Comment: Could you please write when those max(),min(),range(),max(x) *1.25 should be ? ;)) 
I'm not sure if I got the point.

Comment: Edited my answer. We manually calculate the aaxis limits, extend them and based on that also add the gridlines.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:

### ggplot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(69)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

### base R plot:

```r
par(mar = c(5, 5, 1, 1))
plot(df$x, df$y, type = "l", xlab = "x", ylab = "y", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
axis(side = 1, at = 0:4 * 25, tcl = -0.25)
axis(side = 2, las = 1, tcl = -0.25)
rect(-5, -5, 110, 110, col = "#ebebeb")
abline(v = 0:10 * 12.5, col = "white")
abline(h = seq(-3, 3, 0.5), col = "white")
lines(df$x, df$y)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: How did you choose those specific numbers ? I mean, is there a possibility to make it more generic ?

Comment: @John I looked at the ggplot and copied it. To copy every aspect of ggplot programatically would mean rewriting ggplot. I'm sure there are a few shortcuts that could give reasonable results under certain circumstances, but perhaps if you gave a clearer idea of what you're trying to achieve that would help?